# jsPlumb makeSource draggable move bug

Tags: draggable, move, repaint, jsplumb, connector

I found a problem when setting the MapSource connectors.

In jsFiddle code, click on "Reverse" to plot again. When you try to move a div, notice that the background of the DIV it is with an open connector.

Commenting the following code:

```
instancia.makeSource(elem.pageSourceId, {
  paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"transparent" },
  //hoverPaintStyle: endpointHoverStyle,
  //connectorPaintStyle: connectorPaintStyle,
  //connectorHoverPaintStyle: connectorHoverStyle
});
```

This bug does not happen anymore, but I need this code to maintain the original style. Anyone have any idea what it might be?

https://jsfiddle.net/braziel/dvhh7hvg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read carefully [Creating an Endpoint](http://jsplumb.org/doc/endpoints.html) to understand what happens:

Endpoints are created in a number of different ways:

1. [jsPlumb.makeSource(...)](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_makeSource) - Makes some DOM element(s) a Connection source, allowing you to drag connections from it/them without having to first register any Endpoints. 
   [jsPlumb.makeTarget(...)](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_makeTarget) - Makes some DOM element(s) a Connection target, allowing you to drag connections to it/them without having to first register any Endpoints.
2. [jsPlumb.connect(...)](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_connect) - Establishes a Connection between two elements (or Endpoints, which are themselves registered to elements).
3. [jsPlumb.addEndpoint(...)](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_addEndpoint) - Adds an Endpoint to a given element or elements.

You try to use all the methods in your example and as result you are creating a lot of endpoints wich you can't control. My suggestion is to choose only one way and use it.

Comment: I understood what was going on, however, resolve this problem brought me back to the original problem.
When I remove the other methods and leave only the connect, the style of anchor and endpoint are wrong, have any suggestions on how I can set the style?